# After performing operation on column matrix having larger values getting different matrix dimensions in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, multidimensional-array

Consider matrix1 as m1 and matrix2 as m2.So below are the operations to obtain m2.m1 is column matrix.m2 is mxn matrix.In my example m1 is 5x1 matrix and m2 is 5x5 matrix.

---

*Operation to obtain diagonal elements of m2:*

m2(1,1)=m1(1,1)

m2(2,2)=m1(2,1)

m2(3,3)=m1(3,1)

m2(4,4)=m1(4,1)

m2(5,5)=m1(5,1)

*Operation to obtain other elements of m2:*

Equation:**r(i,j)=min(p(i,k),q(j,k)) where k=1**

m2(1,2)=min(m1(1,1),m1(2,1))

m2(1,3)=min(m1(1,1),m1(3,1))

m2(1,4)=min(m1(1,1),m1(4,1))

m2(1,5)=min(m1(1,1),m1(5,1))

...

...

Source Code I tried:

```
for i = 1:5
    for j = 1:5
        if i == j
           B(i,j) = sum(a(i,1:end));
        else
            minval = 0;
            for k = 1
            minval = minval + min(a(i,k),a(j,k));
            end
            B(i,j)= minval;
        end
    end
end
```

This code is working fine for below input matrix:

```
22
 6
10
 6
 8
```

Output matrix i got for this code:

```
22     6    10     6     8
 6     6     6     6     6
10     6    10     6     8
 6     6     6     6     6
 8     6     8     6     8
```

But the code is not working for below input matrix:

```
 610
 442
 699
 464
 774
```

Output matrix iam getting for above input matrix:

matrix of 5 rows and 49 columns.

But expected output matrix:

```
 610  442  610  464  610
 442  442  442  442  442 
 610  442  699  464  699 
 464  442  464  464  464
 610  442  699  464  774
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** one-liner that seems to take care of all your needs -

```
m2 = bsxfun(@min,m1,permute(m1,[3 1 2]))
```

Comment: What is the reason for getting different matrix for different inputs?

Comment: Different matrix for different inputs? Didn't get you there. What do you mean?

Comment: @user3448813 Just curious if you could explain in case you had any issue with the answer? Did this answer work for you?

Comment: Its working for my inputs.Just asked what is the reason for it?

Comment: @user3448813 Are you talking about `[3 1 2]`? Those are just dimensions and not sizes. It's a way to take `m1` to the third dimension and then perform vector comparisons against the original `m1`. If you are talking about why m2 is `5x5` for m1 as `5x1`, it's because the way you are doing element-wise comparisons, but I don't think you are wondering about it as you yourself have proposed that in question.

Comment: 22
 6
10
 6
 8 My code was working fine for this but not for 610
 442
 699
 464
 774

Comment: @user3448813 Using `m1` as `[610 442 699 464 774]`, the values of `m2` as calculated by my code doesn't produce the expected results that you have posted? It worked for me. What values are you getting?

Comment: Yours code is working fine.I got expected output.But my code that i have posted not working.So i asked what is the reason.

Comment: Oh ok. Well the implementation just suited perfectly with `bsxfun` and loops seems like a complicated enough idea :)